# How to use regex in htaccess to redirect certain URLS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect this url format, `http://domain.com/state/city/category/ad-title` to another specific domain such as `http://domain2.com/city`

so anything matching that format above would be redirected. but the issue is, I have 50 or so of those links to redirect.
So i want to redirect for example

```
domain.com/state1/city1/category1/ad-title to
domain2.com/city1
```

and then redirect

```
domain.com/state2/city2/category1/ad-title to
domain.com/city2
```

and so forth. what sort of regex do i need to write just to match any of the above format `/ad-title` and redirect to another domain? This will be a `301` redirect.

Comment: Only the /ad-title will have multiple variables, the city/state/category will all be written in plain text

Answer (score 0):

This redirect rule should work from site root .htaccess as **your very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/[\w-]+/[\w-]+/?$ http://domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You should edit your question and provide this code there as it can't be read from comments.

Comment: good, my suggested rule should also work as your very first rule